# Are both CSV and nLocktime unnecessary in Eltoo?

Tags: lightning-network, locktime, checksequenceverify, eltoo

The Eltoo paper says "Notice that we could use nSequence for this purpose, but due to the interplay with OP_CSV we opted to use nLocktime". Now that [Lau showed CSV not to be necessary](https://lists.linuxfoundation.org/pipermail/bitcoin-dev/2018-December/016574.html), does that mean that there is also no reason to use nLocktime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Anthony Towns' recent draft](https://lists.linuxfoundation.org/pipermail/lightning-dev/2019-December/002362.html) uses CLTV, which [also uses nLocktime](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0065.mediawiki#summary).